# how to fix error when install bluetooth-escpos-printer?

Tags: printing

I want to make my app, can print so I have run **npm install react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer --save**
as [enter link description here](https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer) documentation.
after that I want to make it sure that my project running well after it,
but I found error like [image], and when I try to **link** the project the error using this command **react-native link react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer**

it also bring me to the another error like  **Unrecognized command "link"**.
i dont have idea hot to fix it, please anyone can tell what am I suppose todo

Answer (score 0):

Since no one is maintaining this package. I used https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer/pull/114 which is one of the PR for this package which resolved the insecure protocols and used https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package to keep the changes. Hope it helps!